# waf : passing compiler flags to qt's moc

Tags: qt, waf, moc

I my trying to run a project using `waf` which uses `boost` library . To overcome a [problem](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-22829) I need to pass and `-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED` argument to `MOC`. I tried doing so in the `wscript` as

```
   bld(features ='cxx',
       source   ='GSTEngine.cpp',
       target   = 'GSTEngine.o',
       includes = qtinc+gstinc+taginc,use=['BOOST'],
       uselib   = qtlibs,
       cxxflags = ['-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS','-DBOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED'])
```

but it failed. How to pass argument to `MOC` using `waf`?

Comment: Are you sure these need to be passed to moc? They look like generic defines and should be defined via "bld(..., defines=['QT_NO_KEYWORDS', 'BOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED'], ...)" as can be seen at http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html section 9.1.2

Answer (score 0):

The possible issue here is that `waf` invokes a [new task for `moc`](https://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/waflib/Tools/qt4.py#209) that may not carry the same  `cxxflags` as the task generator that you have defined above.

A possible fix would be to add the defines to the `waf` environment like so:

```
conf.env.append_unique('DEFINES',
    ['QT_NO_KEYWORDS','BOOST_TT_HAS_OPERATOR_HPP_INCLUDED'])
```

If you would just like to add the defines to the `moc` task you could implement a custom feature and add it to your task generator that digs out the `moc` task and adds the defines.